# Pass value to Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to make a function with regular expression [javascript].

Please take a look.

```
function ReplaceIt(key)
{
var KeyCode = /.body\s*\{([^\}]*?)\}/m; // i want to replace the body to the key
}

var key ="h1";
ReplaceIt(key);
```

so the final result will be

```
var Keycode = /.h1\s*\{([^\}]*?)\}/m;
```

I am little bit newbie with javascript and I don't know how to search other resources.

`Note`: Friends, why are you deleting the answers?? Each and every comment/answer is helping us to improve, but we will choose the most appropriate/best answer, please don't delete comments/answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RegExp` with a string to build up your regular expression. If you build the regular expression that way, you should escape all '\'. So your function could look like:

```
function ReplaceIt(key)
{
  return RegExp('.'+key+'\\s*\\{([^\\}]*?)\\}','m');
}
var reKey = ReplaceIt('h1'); //=> /.h1\s*\{([^\}]*?)\}/m
```

Comment: In your jsfiddle, you didn't escape '\' in `re = new RegExp('.' + key + '\s*\{([^\}]*?)\}', 'm');`. Use `re = new RegExp('.' + key + '\\s*\{([^\\}]*?)\\}', 'm')`;

Comment: `Error:

Problem at line 1 character 36: Bad escapement.

var re = RegExp('.' + 'h' + '\\s*\{([^\\}]*?)\\}', 'm');`